# keeping track of multiple uibutton states in uitableview swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift3

i am making an app that has a button per row in a uitable view and the for that code is as follows.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 95
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(numberOfButtonsNeeded!)!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cellIdentifier = "lightCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell


    cell.lightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchDown)
    cell.lightButton?.tag = tags[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

essentially all i want is one button that performs 2 functions and i want to now keep track of the button and whether or not it has been pressed.

if the button has been pressed i would like it to show a certain image called "on.jpg" and perform a certain action.
if the button has not been pressed i would like it to show "off.jpg" and to perform a different action.

the button should be in either one of the two states (pressed or not pressed) and there should be no intermediate state.

my button pressed method is as follows:

```
func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton){

     if ("certain condition is met"){
            guard let image = UIImage(named: "on.jpg") else {
                print("Image Not Found")
                return
            }
            sender.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
        }

     else if ("another condition is met"){
            guard let image = UIImage(named: "off.jpg") else {
                print("Image Not Found")
                return
            }
            sender.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
    }
```

I've tried using tags and variables assigned to each button to try and do it but it just becomes too complicated and there must surely be an easier way to keep track.

Lastly, how would i go about refreshing the tableview and making sure that all the states are always synchronized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a boolean variable in your table dataSource and sets its default value which is true of false. While on button click you can do your code like this

```
func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton){

     let isPressed = dataSource[sender.tag].isButtonPressed
    if isPressed {
       /// Button Already Pressed
    } else {
      /// Button is not pressed
    }
    dataSource[sender.tag].isButtonPressed = !isPressed
}
```

Furthermore you table delegates with remain same.

Comment: I've created an array dataSource which looks  var dataSource : [Bool] = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false], however i get an error saying "value of type bool has no member 'isbuttonpressed'" ...

Comment: for your created array  dataSource : [Bool] = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false‌​,false,false,false,f‌​alse,false,false] function will be look like this

func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton){

     let isPressed = dataSource[sender.tag]
    if isPressed {
       /// Button Already Pressed
    } else {
      /// Button is not pressed
    }
    dataSource[sender.tag] = !isPressed
}

Try this one and tell me if you have any further issue.

Comment: thank you for this, I modified your answer a bit to get it to work... instead of using sender.tag i used index path.row